# Passing multiple argments via asp:button CommandArgument

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

When I pass multiple arguments via

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" 
            CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" 
            CommandName="UpdateCoordinator" 
            CommandArgument='<%# Bind("iUserID") & "," & Bind("siteID")%>' 
            CausesValidation="false" />
```

And in code behind I attempt to split the `CommandArgument` like this:

```
Dim commandArgs As String() = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(New Char() {","})
Dim iUserID As Integer = Val(commandArgs(0))
Dim iSiteID As Integer = Val(commandArgs(1))
```

I am only getting the first argument and the error

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Any assistance to point out what I am missing would be fantastic!

Comment: Based on your title this question and related answers might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822827/how-to-pass-multiple-values-through-command-argument-in-asp-net

Comment: how is your `new Char()` array taking string members.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using Container.DataItem() in the definition of the Button.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" CommandName="UpdateCoordinator" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem("iUserID").ToString() & "," & Container.DataItem("siteID").ToString() %>' CausesValidation="false" />
```